# How to compare dates in android SQLite

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I am building Android app using jquery + phone gap every thing looked green green till i got hit with an issue while comparing dates. I have a requirement to compare dates in my app and having problem in doing so.

I store date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00` (for example: `2013-4-8 00:00:00`) and in my `JavaScript` i was trying to fetch the records using:

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT no, cust_m_no, date_p from CONTACTS WHERE Datetime(date_) >= Datetime('2013-4-8 00:00:00).
```

The above select statement returns 0 records,
is my date comparision wrong in the select statement?
Thanks for any help in Advance.

Comment: You should use '2013-04-08 00:00:00'. The datetime() function returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: dtmilano and yaqub Ahmad Thanks for your clues, it helped.